# CLI: Extract metadata, properties from video files

Tags: command-line, video, metadata

I would like to extract some properties and metadata from video files, e.g.:

- Resolution
- Codec
- Sound quality and format

How do I do it form the command line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look for `mediainfo` package in repository

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57019943/3405122